# Is there a generic workflow for solving 'Option clashes' errors?

Tags: errors

A brief search shows over 20 questions related to package specific option clashes. Maybe the experts can help here - **is there a generic workflow for solving this, that is commonly used?**

Last night my document still compiled, today I did some minor changes and suddenly my glossary, index and citations don't show up because of an option clash.

Is there a way to check package inclusion orders or even maybe a package that handles package inclusion order?

Currently I'm jumping around in my .log file but not having any fun with that.

A cat, grep, sort sequence on all my includes yield a list of packages alphabetically so it's easy to detect doubles and work towards fixing this.

```
cat *filenames_here* | grep 'usepackage' | sort > dump_package_depend.txt
```

Is there a LaTeX/better/systematic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing `h` to the prompt tells you the options that are causing a problem and suggests putting all the options in the `\documentclass` line. Depending on things that sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. When it doesn't you can instead try to specify the options using `\RequirePackage` before the `\documentclass`

```
\RequirePackage[usenames, pdftex,dvipsnames, svgnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass[silent, x11names, justified, twoside]{tufte-book}
```